# Java J2E can't use sendRedirect() in my servlet

Tags: java

I've got an error I can't seem to correct on my own

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        if ((boolean)session.getAttribute("usertype") == true) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            User user = dao.ReturnUserID(userID);
            dao.DeleteUser(user);
            dao.Close();

            response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/admin");
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
}
```

I get an error in the response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/admin"), saying that I can't use sendRedirect() because response is already sent.

The error should have been pretty straightforward, except that i don't understand WHERE i have sent anything in this code...

Here is the exact stack trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Impossible d''appeler "sendRedirect()" après que la réponse ait été envoyée
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
com.SupTracking.servlets.admindeluser.doGet(admindeluser.java:39)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try placing all the url in variable and use only one sendRedirect at the end

Comment: Something in your code has already begun committing a response before you redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call `sendRedirect` once for the response object.  You should change your logic so you know it will only be called once like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        if ((boolean)session.getAttribute("usertype") == true) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            User user = dao.ReturnUserID(userID);
            dao.DeleteUser(user);
            dao.Close();

            response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/admin");
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
    }
}
```

Your problem is:

```
 if ((boolean)session.getAttribute("usertype") == true) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            User user = dao.ReturnUserID(userID);
            dao.DeleteUser(user);
            dao.Close();

            response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/admin");******Called Here**********
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");*******Also Called Here**********
```

You can't redirect multiple times the response can only redirect to one page.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `return` statement after each redirection. Otherwise you redirect many times if one or both if conditions are true.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        if ((boolean)session.getAttribute("usertype") == true) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            User user = dao.ReturnUserID(userID);
            dao.DeleteUser(user);
            dao.Close();

            response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/admin");
            return;
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
        return;
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your sendRedirect() is called many times on response object as your conditions are becoming true.

Try this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        if ((boolean)session.getAttribute("usertype") == true) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
            User user = dao.ReturnUserID(userID);
            dao.DeleteUser(user);
            dao.Close();

         }
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/SupTracking/index");
}
```